# Move Sonarqube from one computer to another

Tags: sonarqube, migration, backup, code-analysis

I have Sonarqube Community Edition 8.4.1 (build 35646) running locally on Windows 10.
My company provided me with the new laptop and I need to move there all the sonar data (and scan results). I have spent few weeks analysing X amount of repos and will have to talk to each team about the issues that were found so it's really important to keep that data.
How can I do it?

PS: I am new to Sonar and I saw it first time in my life 4 weeks ago.
I have to move everything to cloud and I will not have 2 laptops at the same time to experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case somebody has the same problem:
I copied the following folders to the new laptop and I got all the projects with analysis results displaying

1. sonarqube folder
2. Sonar-scanner folder
3. .sonar folder (just in case)
4. .sonarlint (just in case)
5. .m2 (just in case)